# Showing the nth roots of unity satisfy two properties

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

Assuming $ω_0,ω_1,...,ω_n$ are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity, I am asked to show $$(x−ω_0)(x−ω_1)···(x−ω_{n−1}) =x^n−1$$ and $$\sum^{n−1}_{a=0}ω_a= 0$$ 
I understand that by definition, the $n^{th}$ roots of unity are the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$. I'm not sure I know the properties of the roots of unity well enough to even know where to begin.

Thank you.

Comment: what is $x_n$ ?

Comment: Should the RHS of your main equation have been `x^n-1` rather than `x_{n-1}`?

Comment: The second identity fails for $n=1$.

Comment: In the first line of your question, you listed $n+1$ $n^{th}$ roots of unity!

Answer (score 0):

Since omegas are the roots of $x^n-1$

You can factor $x^n-1$ to get  $$x^n-1=(x−ω_0)(x−ω_1)···(x−ω_{n−1}) $$

The sum of roots of a monomial  of degree $n$ is the opposite of the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ which in this case is $0$

Answer (score 0):

Since the roots of unity are the roots of the polynomial $p(z)=z^n-1$, and since the coefficient of the $z$ term is $0$, it follows immediately that $\sum \omega_a=0$. And since the roots of unity split the polynomial completely over $\mathbb C$, it follows again at once that $p(z)=\prod (z-\omega_a)=z^n-1.$

Answer (score 0):

If you pick a primitive root $\zeta$ for n>1 then we can represent all of the other roots as powers of it.

$$\sum_{a=0}^{n-1} \omega_a = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \zeta^k$$

This rearrangement makes all the difference since now it's the geometric series,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \zeta^k = \frac{\zeta^n-1}{\zeta-1}$$

Because $n>1$ then $\zeta \ne 1$ and so there's no issue with the denominator. Since $\zeta$ is a root of $x^n-1$ the numerator is $0$ which is what you wanted to show.